# When recording using UIAutomation on a device, it hangs on 'Starting Capture...' . Works fine on Simulator

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4.5, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Has anyone else had this problem?

I'm new to UIAutomation. Am using Xcode4.5, trying to record commands on my iPad 3 running ios6. When I click the record button, it just hangs on 'Starting Capture...'. I had this problem initially when trying to run on the simulator and was able to solve it using. sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. Can't seem to get it working on my device. Do the accessibility settings need to be set a certain way? I have multi-tasking turned on.

When I try to run a script, nothing  happens. No errors or anything. Totally stumped.

Comment: I am facing same problem with simulator. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the app is compiled using a Development Provisioning Profile and not an Ad-hoc one.