# Testing ipa with UIAutomation on device, hangs up on starting capture

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ipa, ios-ui-automation

I have an .ipa file which I re signed with my development profile. I have insalled the app on ipad. Now when I am using `UIAutomation` for testing of that ipa, `UIAutomation` hangs up on Starting Capture...

Any idea or solution for the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When recording using UIAutomation on a device, it hangs on 'Starting Capture...' . Works fine on Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327885/when-recording-using-uiautomation-on-a-device-it-hangs-on-starting-capture)

Comment: Answer provided in link given by James Moore, does not works for me as I have already resigned the .ipa file with my Development Provisioning Profile.